# How to allow AD group to access and manage IIS sites and pools?

Tags: windows, active-directory, security, iis, user-permissions

i manage actually a domain with around 34 IIS servers running webapplications.

I would like to get a better user right management in my domain.

For the moment, my users allowed to manage IIS websites and pools are members of the Domain Admins group which is not really secure.

For getting more control i would like to create an AD group containing the users allowed to manage IIS sites and pools ans only let them manage this part of the server.

But, i don't know how to proceed for allowing this group to acces and manage IIS websites.

I've read some article on Technet explaining how to do this manually but i got lot of servers running IIS and lot of users and i cannot do it by hand
here it is : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/leesab/2014/07/30/delegating-iis-administration-to-domain-users-non-administrators/

My users access to the management console from RDP connection. They can open the console but they don't see any website in the left pane.

Can you help me ?

Comment: No. Such users must install IIS Manager on their local machines (Windows 7 or 10), https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=41177 and then connect to the remote IIS. You cannot let them using RDP.